# how can i transofrm an object in array to perform in ngfor in angular?

Tags: angular

I have this object that i need to do a *ngfor:

```
{produtos: Array(50)}
produtos: Array(50)
0: {id: 27, id_admin: 249, tipo_produto: {…}, nome: "fsafasf", valor_fornecedor: 0, …}
```

My template:

```
<div *ngFor="let produto of data" class="card">
```

I receive:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'.

how can i transform this object in arrays?

Comment: ```<div *ngFor="let item of data.produtos">{{item.id}}</div>```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object no need to tranform it as its already containing your array in the first key “produto”
You miss to access your object key has an array so,
Make it like

```
<div *ngFor="let produto of data.produto" class="card">p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objectKeys = Object.keys(data);

  <div *ngFor="let key of objectKeys" class="card">
   {{ data[key].propery }}
  </div>
```

You can get your object keys in array by using `Object.keys(yourObject)`, and do `*ngFor` on that array, getting your object data by this way `data[key]`

or another way you can get your object values by using  `Object.values(yourObject)`

```
objectValues = Object.values(data);

    <div *ngFor="let value of objectValues" class="card">
     {{ value.property}}
    </div>
```